I may go to the party. I might go to the party

I may go to the party.


I might go to the party.

What's the difference?
People say the possibility of going is higher with 'may'.
Is this true?
But also they say that in case of 'may have pp' and 'might have pp' 'might have pp' has higher possibility.

He may have gone to the party.


He might have gone to the party.

Is this true?

What do you think is the difference? What research have you done and what don't you understand about it? Please edit your question and add this information so that we can understand your problem.

I edited my question more specifically.

Sometimes it is true, sometimes not.  It depends on how might is used in the sentence.

In the present tense, it doesn't make much difference.
In the past tense, if something may have happened, we don't know whether it happened or not. If it might have happened, it was a possibility but we now know that it didn't.
(That's my take on it, at least, though journalists and others often ignore the distinction. "If he had done this, the accident may not have happened" sounds wrong to me when the accident did happen.)

your take applies also to "may as well have+pp" and "might as well have+pp"? I don't think so because both mean it didn't happen. Might be here any difference between 'may as well have pp' and 'might as well have pp'?

You should ask "Does your take also apply to...?" Might as well have is much more common in this context. May as well is used more in the context of an unenthusiastic suggestion. "We may as well do that, since there's nothing better to do."

Your example "If he had done this, the accident may not have happened" is in the subjunctive mood of past perfect which indicates the reverse of acutal fact in the past, so using 'may' is not wrong as you said and 'might' is right.

What is your authority for saying that may is the subjunctive?

My authority happens due to 'had+pp' together with 'if'. If you use "If+had+pp", it means the reverse of the actual fact in the past. For example, "If I had married her" means "I didn't marry her in the past." This concept is very strict in school exams.

I meant in the previous comment that "may" is" wrong".

**But if what was once a possibility is no longer perfectly probable, but simply a hypothetical thing which never in fact did become a real event - if nobody died or got ill and we know it - you must use might: -
The island is still flooded and people might have caught awful diseases...
(...but luckily they'd all had their typhoid and dysentery vaccinations.)** From This Itch of Writing

The nuance you provided here is excellent. Many students and non-native teachers think "may have pp" and "might have pp" are the same.

Sometimes it is true, sometimes not.  It depends on how might is used in the sentence.
it might can have the meaning "it can" or "there would be nothing to stop it" whereas "I might" can suggest less likelihood than "I may".

Don't set the bottle down on that bunched tablecloth. It might tip over.
If the enemy take the high ground, they might then take the entire town.
Are you going to the presentation?  -- Not sure, with this upset stomach. I might.

Modals tend to have a range of meanings.

The 'take' in your "If the enemy take the high ground" is in the present subjunctive mood? I aks this due to the base form of the verb 'take': take (not takes)

@gomadeng It's possible to construe the enemy as singular or plural.   Here the speaker thinks of it as plural ("they migjht").

The short answer is that you are correct in your first statement. In my opinion, may is more likely then might.
The following examples are not to be taken as absolute, there is a grey area where may and might can be interchanged.

I may go to the party if the weather is fine / if I can afford the train fare.


I might go to the party if I I've nothing better to do.

May has a slightly more positive outlook to it than might, but again this is more my opinion than 100% fact.
As to your second edit (applied whilst I was writing my answer). I disagree, may is still more likely then might.
By the way, what do you mean by "pp"? I've never come across it, is it some form of texteese?

Thx 4 answer. 'pp' means 'past participle'
